# Out of Browser in Silverlight2

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

How can I build a Stand Alone Application with Silverlight 2.

1.I know that Silverlight 3 has the Out of Browser Functionality to build such Applications. But it is in beta and I cannot wait for it.
 2. I also had a look at 
Desklighter(http://www.blendables.com/labs/Desklighter/Default.aspx) which helps to build a executable from a xap file. But it needs .Net Framework to run, which beats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

just build a winform app and host iexplore ocx ,
point the ocx to an html page that contains the silverlight app.
there is a dotnet example on tamir khasons blog http://khason.net/blog/stand-alone-multiplatform-silverlight-application/
but it can be achived in any language

Comment: Won't that require .NET too, which the author says defeats the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

well! if you want to go for that particular purpose i agree with daniel's solution.. 
now regarding @James, yep it will defeat the purpose instead try developing the host in c++ then...